# Setting button drawable for RadioButton using drawable xml not working for checked state

Tags: android, radio-button, xml-drawable

I've got a group of radio buttons, and I want to set the button's background to a solid color when checked. I created a drawable resource, using a selector and item def's like:

```
<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false"

      android:drawable="@color/app_tint"/>
```

with several variations while trying to get it to work. In the layout containing the buttons, I've tried setting both button and background properties (not at the same time, just one or the other in testing) like:

```
android1:background="@drawable/radio_state"
```

OR

```
android1:button="@drawable/radio_state"
```

I've read several posts, and I feel I'm close, just missing something to get it done. Thanks.

Comment: tried setting background property to the selector, and then setting transparent color on button, not working. Tried several more variations of the selector items themselves. Still nothing. This makes iOS toolbar items look awesome!! ;-)

Comment: User error... ugh. and iOS toolbar items are still awful ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one we did for an app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bcnav_ebilling_focus"                            
      android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bcnav_ebilling_focus"
      android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bcnav_ebilling_focus"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bcnav_ebilling_focus"
      android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_bcnav_ebilling" />
</selector>
```

Each state has a different drawable, although in this example, we don't really care about all states being very different - just focus=true get a highlighted drawable (it has "..._focus")

Comment: and that works for radio buttons? how are you setting the button in the layout? Which attribute (of the radio button) are you setting the above resource on? Thanks Martin.

Comment: doesn't work; I specified my color for the drawable, and then assigned to both button, then background, then both properties of the radio button in the layout, and nothing. It does highlight when pressed, but it doesn't stick. Thanks Martin

Comment: ok, figured out why I wasn't working; had an override xml in the subproject, but it's file name was incorrect. Sadly, that was the one I was editing... so, fixed the filename issue, and boom!